# h3 and list dropdown menu CSS3

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

got an html list working as a dropdown menu with CSS when you hover through a < li > element like "Products" in my example. But what I want is the same effect when hover through < h3 > like "Contact" from my example. Is it possible?

Here's the html:

```
<h3>Contact</h3>
 <ul>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS code:

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you emphasize on what you want the h3 to do? If you want to hover over Contact and have the list items display block you either will have to use javascript/jquery or you will have to nest the list items within the h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On hover you can only control the CSS of the element you hover over, or the CSS of elements within the element you hover over (one of its children).
So you can not make the `ul` change styles when you hover over the `h3` because they 1) are not the same object and 2) do not have a parent-child relationship (they are siblings).

To show the menu when hovering over the h3, you can wrap both of them inside another object (`div`) and use this for the hover event. To distinguish between the two hovers you can add classnames to both the `ul`s.

[See this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvtxdw0r/1/), or the code below:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.container ul{
    display: none;
}
.container:hover ul.menu{
    display: block;
}
ul li ul.submenu {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
```

Comment: Thank you all guys!! that's exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

In short - you should nest `ul` inside the `h3`

```
<h3>
    Contact
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</h3>
```

And in your css:

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
h3 > ul {
     display: none;
}
h3:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mscehjLf/1/

Comment: According to the W3C, only [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is allowed within a [h3 tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h3.html). `ul` is a [flow element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) and should not be used. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @Jasper 100% agree. That's why I marked it 'In short' ;)